# Trying to write Quicksort in D, get OutOfMemoryError

Tags: algorithm, d, quicksort

Currently trying to learn D programming language.

Wrote this little quicksort algo, which returns a OutOfMemoryError when running with the shipped example.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;

int[] qs(int[] ary) 
{
    if(ary.length <= 1)
    {
        return ary;
    }

    int pivot_pos   = 0;
    int pivot       = ary[pivot_pos];

    for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) 
    {
        if(ary[i] < pivot) 
        {
            ary = ary.remove(i) ~ ary;
            pivot_pos++;
        }
        else 
        {
            ary ~= ary.remove(i);
            if(i < pivot_pos)
                pivot_pos--;
        }
    }

    return qs(ary[0..pivot_pos]) ~ qs(ary[(pivot_pos+1)..ary.length]);
}

int main() 
{

    int[] ary = [ 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 78, 3, 5, 10, 129, 234, 3, 5 ];

    ary = qs(ary);

    foreach(int element; ary) 
    {
        printf("%d ", element);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any hints how to solve this or what's wrong in the algo? Any tips how to learn D and what I have to care about?

Answer (score 5):

you are using concatenation. this will allocate a new array each time (the only time it won't is when there is unallocated memory beyond the array), and the way you partition the arrays keeps a reference to enough parts that the GC wont be able to sweep them all

you should use swap:

```
auto tmp=ary;
while(tmp.length) 
{
    if(tmp[0]==pivot)break;//assumes unique
    if(tmp[0]<pivot) 
    {
        tmp=tmp[1..$];
        pivot_pos++;
    }
    else 
    {
        swap(tmp[0],tmp[$-1]);
        tmp=tmp[0..$-1];
    }
}
```

or just use [std.algorithm.partition](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#partition) for it the source of it can be found [here](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/algorithm.d#L7657)